# How to remove duplicate title and meta description tags if google indexed them

Tags: seo, meta, google-search-console

So, I have been building an ecommerce site for a small company.

The url structure is : www.example.com/product_category/product_name and the site has around 1000 products.

I've checked google webmaster tools and in the HTML improvements section it shows that I have multiple title and meta description tags for all the product pages. They all appear two times, both:

-www.example.com/product_category/product_name

and

-www.example.com/product_category/product_name/ (with slash in the end)

got indexed as separate pages.

I've added a 301 redirect from every www.example.com/product_category/product_name/ to www.example.com/product_category/product_name, but this was almost two weeks ago. I have resubmitted my sitemap and asked google to fetch the whole page a few times. Nothing has changed, GWT still shows the pages as duplicate tags.

I did not get any manual action message.

So I have two questions:

-**how can I accelerate the reindexation process, if it's possible?**

-and **do these tags hurt my organic search results?** I've googled it, yes and some say it does and some say it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to set a canonical link on both URLs (with and without /) using the URL without a /. Little by little, Google will stop complaining. Keep in mind Google Webmaster Tools is slow to react, especially when you don't have much traffic or backlinks.

And yes, duplicate tags can influence your rankings negatively because users won't have proper and specific information for each page.

Comment: Canonical would be a better solution than 301 redirect?

Comment: In your case, it would eliminate duplicate indexing more efficiently. Ultimately, 301 would do the job too, but my experience is that it can a long time for GWT to report it right.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change it to cannonical.

Answer (score 0):

Set a canonical link on both Urls is a solution but it take time from my experience.
The fasted way is to block old URL in robots.txt file.

```
 Disallow: /old_url
```

Answer (score 0):

canonical tag is option but why you are not adding different title and description for all pages.

you can add dynamic meta tags one time and it will create automatically for all pages so we dont worry about duplication.